# How can I generate a flat stone world on Minecraft XBox?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

Is there a nice seed for generating a flat world made of *stone* in Minecraft 1.8.2 for Xbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the last update you can now create a superflat world but as @Wikwocket said, it will be made of dirt and not stone.

Comment: You don't need a mod as of 1.4: you an [generate flat worlds with any type of block](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Pretty_Scary_Update#World_Generation).

Comment: @MarkTrapp true that

Comment: You can make a superflat world in XBox as of the [latest update](http://www.mojang.com/2012/10/new-minecraft-xbox-360-edition-update-is-out/), but I think it will be of dirt, not stone.

Answer (score 0):

You can hit “edit layers” and then state how many stone you want.